# Probable quoting issue using the stdin argument of ansible's shell module

Tags: ansible, jq, aws-cli, ansible-2.x

I've got a playbook with the following tasks:

```
- set_fact:
    asg_filter: >
      .AutoScalingGroups[] |
      select(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Role").Value == "myrole")
- shell: aws autoscaling --region us-west-2 describe-auto-scaling-groups | jq --compact-output "{{ asg_filter }}"
  register: asgs_result
- set_fact:
    stale_instance_filter: >
      .LaunchConfigurationName as $lc |
      .Instances[] |
      select(.LaunchConfigurationName != $lc) |
      .InstanceId
```

Now I want to use `stale_instance_filter` on `asgs_result.stdout`. The following works:

```
- shell: echo '{{ asgs_result.stdout }}' | jq -r '{{ stale_instance_filter }}'
```

But this doesn't:

```
- shell: jq -r '{{ stale_instance_filter }}'
  args:
    stdin: "{{ asgs_result.stdout }}"
```

I get the following error message: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 23` (which I believe is from the account number in the ARN for the ASG.) I think it's a quoting issue (maybe something about the double quotes in the JSON), but I've also tried `asgs_result.stdout | quote` to no avail. I also tried the `command` module; it didn't help either. Of course this all works if I do it directly on the CLI.

I realize I could combine the two `jq` filters but I want to reuse `asgs_result` for other things and don't want to have to make the query multiple times. How can I fix this so I can use the `stdin` argument?

Edit: I was asked to provide an example of the value of asgs_result, well here you go, here's the `stdout` attribute in it (since I don't use anything else):

```
"stdout": "{\"AutoScalingGroupARN\":\"arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:123456:autoScalingGroup:e75a213b-75fe-467c-8cf5-d7c51f76c471:autoScalingGroupName/myrole-dev\",\"TargetGroupARNs\":[],\"SuspendedProcesses\":[],\"DesiredCapacity\":4,\"Tags\":[{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"dev\",\"Key\":\"Dimension\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResouJceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"true\",\"Key\":\"Monitored\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"myrole\",\"Key\":\"Name\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"myrole\",\"Key\":\"Role\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"2035-09-30 18:55:31 +0000\",\"Key\":\"cleaner-destroy-after\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"vpce-2c23ca45\",\"Key\":\"force_s3_endpoint_dependency\"},{\"ResourceType\":\"auto-scaling-group\",\"ResourceId\":\"myrole-dev\",\"PropagateAtLaunch\":true,\"Value\":\"owned\",\"Key\":\"kubernetes.io/cluster/dev\"}],\"EnabledMetrics\":[],\"LoadBalancerNames\":[],\"AutoScalingGroupName\":\"myrole-dev\",\"DefaultCooldown\":300,\"MinSize\":4,\"Instances\":[{\"ProtectedFromScaleIn\":false,\"AvailabilityZone\":\"us-east-2b\",\"InstanceId\":\"i-0141fd35e3cf3ad0a\",\"HealthStatus\":\"Healthy\",\"LifecycleState\":\"InService\",\"LaunchConfigurationName\":\"dev_myrole_20180511171410107500000002\"},{\"ProtectedFromScaleIn\":false,\"AvailabilityZone\":\"us-east-2c\",\"InstanceId\":\"i-01aec2b3546d75190\",\"HealthStatus\":\"Healthy\",\"LifecycleState\":\"InService\",\"LaunchConfigurationName\":\"dev_myrole_20180511171410107500000002\"},{\"ProtectedFromScaleIn\":false,\"AvailabilityZone\":\"us-east-2a\",\"InstanceId\":\"i-0830b227f034d2859\",\"HealthStatus\":\"Healthy\",\"LifecycleState\":\"InService\",\"LaunchConfigurationName\":\"dev_myrole_20180511171410107500000002\"},{\"ProtectedFromScaleIn\":false,\"AvailabilityZone\":\"us-east-2b\",\"InstanceId\":\"i-0f7d847e8c168040b\",\"HealthStatus\":\"Healthy\",\"LifecycleState\":\"InService\",\"LaunchConfigurationName\":\"dev_myrole_20180511171410107500000002\"}],\"MaxSize\":4,\"VPCZoneIdentifier\":\"subnet-c348988e,subnet-79743210,subnet-156ee36e\",\"HealthCheckGracePeriod\":300,\"TerminationPolicies\":[\"Default\"],\"LaunchConfigurationName\":\"dev_myrole_20180511171410107500000002\",\"CreatedTime\":\"2018-02-20T22:35:32.183Z\",\"AvailabilityZones\":[\"us-east-2a\",\"us-east-2b\",\"us-east-2c\"],\"HealthCheckType\":\"EC2\",\"NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn\":false}"
```

Sorry that it is all on one line but I don't want to make anyone think there is a newline in there, because there isn't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to retrieve raw output, then load it as JSON with the `from_json` filter, then parse it with jinja2 filters or [`json_query`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)?

Comment: @peak if you'll re-read my post you'll see that I tried that.

Comment: @zigarn I'm really not used to doing that but I suppose it will sidestep the problem, but for the sake of finding an answer to my question I'd still like to find out how to solve it as asked, even if eventually I use `from_json`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the value of `asgs_result`. (BTW, I would says that the problem is that the `stdin` is evaluating the JSON value and not keeping it as a simple string)

Comment: Try to use the `to_json` to force it to be a string.

Comment: @zigarn I added an example. `to_json` doesn't work, I get this error: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string \"LaunchConfigurationName\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON content seems to be interpreted before sent to the stdin, so looks like simple quotes are sent (seen in verbose mode with `-vvv`):

```
"stdin": "{'AutoScalingGroupARN': 'arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:123456:autoScalin
gGroup:e75a213b-75fe-467c-8cf5-d7c51f76c471:autoScalingGroupName/myrole-dev', ...,
 'AvailabilityZones': ['us-east-2a', 'us-east-2b', 'us-east-2c']}"
```

Which is not JSON valid:

```
$ echo "{'AutoScalingGroupARN': 'arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:123456:autoScalingGroup:e75a213b-75fe-467c-8cf5-d7c51f76c471:autoScalingGroupName/myrole-dev', 'HealthCheckGracePeriod': 300}" | jq
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 23

$ echo '{"AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:123456:autoScalingGroup:e75a213b-75fe-467c-8cf5-d7c51f76c471:autoScalingGroupName/myrole-dev", "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300}' | jq
{
  "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:123456:autoScalingGroup:e75a213b-75fe-467c-8cf5-d7c51f76c471:autoScalingGroupName/myrole-dev",
  "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300
}
```

So, you need to "escape" it.
Unfortunately, the `to_json` filter, escape to much:

```
"stdin": "\"{\\\"AutoScalingGroupARN\\\":\\\"arn:aws:autosca...
```

But the `string` filter fits perfectly:

```
"stdin": "{\"AutoScalingGroupARN\":\"arn:aws:autosca...
```

**So, the correct way with `stdin` is this**:

```
- shell: jq -r '{{ stale_instance_filter }}'
  args:
    stdin: "{{ asgs_result.stdout | string }}"
```