# How to get ansible playbook to take input for my perlscript.pl which contains <STDIN>?

Tags: perl, ansible, yaml, stdin

In an ansible playbook I use a file containing a perl script file to perform a few tasks. How do I get ansible to capture STDIN for the perl script?

```
> #!/usr/bin/perl -w
> ...
> print OUTPUT_FILE "\n";
> my $datasetid_target = <STDIN>; <<--not able to link to ansible playbook
> $datasetid_target; print OUTPUT_FILE
> qq("datasetId":"$datasetid_target",);
```

The script works well as a standalone but prints nothing with ansible.

I tried using args, vars, expect, stdin with no success.

Expected result is something along the lines of: (please refer to the snapshot)

```
>  - name: edit source file
>    shell: perl "{{ project_dir }}/edit_dataschema.pl"
>    args:
>      stdin:  <<-- here is my problem
>        "{{datasetid_target}}"
```

Comment: Hi Bhargavi, welcome to SO. Please be more specific with what **is** happening; does your program hang? I was able to put together a simple example with `shell: perl -we '$foo = <STDIN>; print qq("foo": "$foo",);'` and it behaved rationally when used with `args: stdin:` so I fear you just have improper expectations

Comment: Hi Matthew, I appreciate the help. Is there a way to pass multiple stdins? For instance: args: stdin: $dataset_target: {{dataset_target}} $tablename: {{tablename}}?

Comment: @BhargaviJagannathan I didn't get you..? multiple inputs in the STDIN meant.? You can make the input in the while loop. Else read the input and split with the space character.

Comment: Rephrasing my question: How can I pass in 3 command line arguments to the perl script using the shell module. I use programname.pl arg1<newline> arg2<newline> arg3. However only the first arg is processed by the script.

Answer (score 1):

First, just in case, do check if passing the parameter on the same line has any influence ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109036/6309)):

```
- name: edit source file
  shell: perl "{{ project_dir }}/edit_dataschema.pl"
  args:
    stdin: "{{datasetid_target}}"
```

Second, check if a [string conversion as made here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343744/6309) would help:

```
  args:
    stdin: "{{datasetid_target | string}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, your string suggestion helped solve the problem. I have another question, I have 2 more stdins in the the same script, any advice on how to handle them on ansible? I'm new to both ansible and perl, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @BhargaviJagannathan If those are for the same STDIN of the same commands, it is better to combine strings into one, to pass to said commands. If those are two different STDIN for two different commands, the approach above should apply, simply repeated/duplicated for the other commands.

Comment: How can I pass in 3 command line arguments to the perl script using the shell module. I use 
{{}}

Comment: @BhargaviJagannathan By duplicating the shell step three time, each one with their own string to pass as STDIN in each shell step.